# Unit test dynamic method call Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have this service in my component and one of its methods is called dynamically

```
@Input methodName: string;

constructor(
        private readonly testService: testService
    ) {
}

loadData() {
   this.testService[this.methodName]().subscribe();
}
```

I

I'm Having a lot of trouble testing the method loadData(), it keeps telling me that this.testService[methodName] is not function, How would you test that kind of method ?

```
it('should ',  fakeAsync(() => {
        // getData is the supposed methodName that has to be set;
        testService.getData.and.returnValue(asyncData({} as any));
        component.loadData();
        flush();
        expect(testService.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

Comment: Let me know if the answer worked for you

Comment: @ShashankVivek it worked thanks ! How would you proceed to mock components ?

Comment: Try https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49 and let me know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: Feel free to upvote as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make the service `public` in component constructor for better testing
2. Follow this example as standard practice:

**service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserSvcService {
  test() {
    return of('test');
  }
}
```

for a **component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-detail',
  templateUrl: './user-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-detail.component.scss'],
})
export class UserDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'test';
  val :string

  public constructor(public _userSvc: UserSvcService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._userSvc[this.name]().subscribe(res =>
      this.val = res
    );
  }
}
```

Create a stub like this:

```
export class UserServiceStub {
  test() {
    return of('test mock');
  }
}
```

replace the actual service with stub as:

```
describe('UserDetailComponent', () => {
  let component: UserDetailComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserDetailComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      declarations: [UserDetailComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: UserSvcService, useClass: UserServiceStub }],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserDetailComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component.val).toBe('test mock'); // move in another "it" block
  });
```

This should work. To make your way to work, you need to create a `spyOn` with service as `public` 1st:

```
it('should ',  () => {       
        spyOn(component.testService,'getData').and.returnValue(return of({some val}));
        component.loadData();
        expect(component.testService.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

This [article](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49) might interest you more